# Simulate mouse click synchronously

Tags: c#, winapi, mouse, simulation

I tried to use `mouse_event()` function, but it seems that it works asynchronously.

Below is my code (the problem is in Main method).
I set mouse position and simulate click, but my code returns the previous window (in the last line) even before click simulation happen.

How to overcome this asynchrony without suspending thread for 100 milliseconds?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace MouseSimulatingTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000); //just for testing - to have time to have an ability to switch to another window

            //remember current foreground window
            IntPtr previousForegroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

            IntPtr browserWindowHandle = GetBrowserWindow();
            //set browser window to foreground to make a click in it
            ForceActivateWindow(browserWindowHandle);
            //make a click
            SetCursorPos(150, 20);
            mouse_event(LEFT_DOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(LEFT_UP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            //Thread.Sleep(100); //if I uncomment this line then everything works perfectly

            //return previous foreground window to top
            ForceActivateWindow(browserWindowHandle);
        }

        const int LEFT_DOWN = 0x00000002;
        const int LEFT_UP = 0x00000004;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        static public void ForceActivateWindow(IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            uint processID;
            uint foregroundThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), out processID);
            uint mainThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
            const uint SW_SHOW = 5;
            if (foregroundThreadID != mainThreadId)
            {
                AttachThreadInput(foregroundThreadID, mainThreadId, true);
                BringWindowToTop(windowHandle);
                ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
                SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
                AttachThreadInput(foregroundThreadID, mainThreadId, false);
            }
            else
            {
                BringWindowToTop(windowHandle);
                ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
                SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
            }
        }

        static IntPtr GetBrowserWindow()
        {
            var browserProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("opera");
            if (browserProcesses.Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("Browser is not opened");
            return browserProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You send an event to another window. It'll process whenever it wants (according to what it's doing and other messages in the queue). Also I'd drop mouse_event() in favor of SendInput().

Comment: Calling `mouse_event` or `SendInput` places input packets into the hardware input queue. Those packets are picked up by the Raw Input Thread. The Raw Input Thread runs at high priority, but there is no guarantee as to when an **application** has finished processing this input. Synthesizing input is wrong for other reasons still. If you want a robust, supported interface, use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107.aspx) instead.